# Conversion of definite integral to continued fraction:

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, continued-fractions, transcendental-numbers

Consider integral of the form :

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

$f(x)$ is analytic and real valued for real domain.

Now fix $a$ and $b$ ( most likely $[0,1]$ and $[0,\infty]$ )  .

> > Can we construct a continued fraction in terms of $f(x)$  , $a$ and $b$  which is equal to the integral  ?
>
> Is/are there such type of standard results in literature exists ?

Comment: You question is not clear. The definite integral could be any real number. Any real number has a [simple continued fraction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html) expansion. What am I missing?

Comment: @Somos edited the question ; thanks

Comment: Still not specific enough. Since $f(x)$ has a Taylor series expansion we have [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula). Same thing even if you integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, almost certainly not (or at least we are very far from being able to do so). Whatever formula or algorithm of this type you envision would presumably apply in particular to
$$
\int_0^1 \frac4{1+x^2}\,dx = \pi,
$$
which is dissonant with the fact that we have no special insight into the continued fraction of $\pi$.

Comment: thank you for the answer . But , mainly this question meant for  : How to find if a definite integral is rational , irrational or transcendental without actually calculating the value (or not  easy to calculate )? Are there numerical analytic methods ?